# How do I parse the PLS playlist format in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I'm developing an iPhone application for a radio station. I'm in need of parsing `playlist.pls` and `playlist.qtl`, to get the stream audio url present in it. I'm stuck with that.

Comment: Post your code. Show us what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Since pls uses ini format, you can parse it using [Properties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). qtl is an xml format, you can find a lot of examples of parsing xml.